# error electrum after ubuntu update

Tags: upgrade

After updating Ubuntu have the following error whe I try to run electrum:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bin/electrum", line 83, in

from electrum.logging import get_logger, configure_logging  # import logging submodule first ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'electrum'

Comment: Neither Ubuntu apt upgrades nor Ubuntu snap refreshes would touch anything in your /home/bin directory. Nor would they install anything there. They don't even know that directory exists. Look to a different cause. Human error is the most common reason for items going missing in /home.

Comment: You didn't specify whether it was a normal daily upgrade or a rare release-upgrade. If the latter, you must upgrade electrum manually to be compatible with your upgraded system...since you apparently installed electrum manually in the first place.

Comment: I upgrade 20.04  to 21.04 ubuntu version. Before that i have updated electrum to the latest version. I understand what you are saying it doesnt matter i already have installed the latest version for electrum. As I have upgrade Ubuntu I have to update electrum again?

Comment: I have installed electrum again it works, but when I run it I get this message in the terminal:  Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway                                                         Any ideas whats going on?